# Interpolate in Scipy, return polynomial

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am using `interp1d` from `scipy.interpolate` for interpolating using a cubic polynomial. Is there any way in which I can extract the coefficients of the cubic polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to obtain the coefficients with `interp1d`, but you could use [`splrep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) instead. It can be used to fit a b-spline and you can set the degree to cubic. It returns a tuple `(t,c,k)` containing the vector of knots `t`, the coefficients `c` and the degree `k`.